# Crash while trying to get a list of installed applications: PackageManager$NameNotFoundException

Tags: android, installed-applications, usagestatsmanager

I have a crash at several users (running android 7.0/7.1) which I can't reproduce.

The crash happens in a module in which I try to get the list of installed app. I tested the app on real hw and all sorts of emulators without issues.

I show below a simplified version of my code.

The line with the crash is:

```
ApplicationInfo ai = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(info.packageName, 0);
```

in the function getInstalledAppList.

ListApptest is a class instantiated from a fragment:

```
ListApptest applications = new ListApp(getActivity());
```

I initialize packageManager as activity.getPackageManager() and it looks like getInstalledApplications() runs fine (I could add a check for the returned value?) so what could be the reason for the PackageManager$NameNotFoundException?

How could getInstalledApplications returns an unknown package name?

Here is my code:

```
class ListApptest {
    private static final int flags = PackageManager.GET_META_DATA |
            PackageManager.GET_SHARED_LIBRARY_FILES |
            PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES;

    private static Context context;
    private static Activity activity;

    private static PackageManager packageManager;

    ListApptest(Activity a, UsageStatsManager u, ListView l, ProgressBar p){
        activity = a;
        packageManager = activity.getPackageManager();
    }

    static class AppsGetInfo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private List<AppsItem> listAppsItem;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            getInstalledApp();
            return null;
        }

        void getInstalledApp() {
            List<String> installedApps = getInstalledAppList();
        }

        private List<String> getInstalledAppList() {
            List<ApplicationInfo> infos = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(flags);
            List<String> installedApps = new ArrayList<>();
            for (ApplicationInfo info : infos) {
                installedApps.add(info.packageName);

                try {
                    // CRASH HERE
                    ApplicationInfo ai = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(info.packageName, 0);

                } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return installedApps;
        }

     }
}
```

Here are the associated trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done (AsyncTask.java:325)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion (FutureTask.java:354)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException (FutureTask.java:223)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run (AsyncTask.java:243)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:762)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
at com.narb.listapp.Applications.ListApp$AppsGetInfo.fromUsageStat (ListApp.java:214)
at com.narb.listapp.Applications.ListApp$AppsGetInfo.buildUsageStatsWrapper (ListApp.java:201)
    at com.narb.listapp.Applications.ListApp$AppsGetInfo.getInstalledApp (ListApp.java:163)
    at com.narb.listapp.Applications.ListApp$AppsGetInfo.doInBackground (ListApp.java:72)
    at com.narb.listapp.Applications.ListApp$AppsGetInfo.doInBackground (ListApp.java:60)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call (AsyncTask.java:305)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:237)

  Caused by: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: 
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfoAsUser (ApplicationPackageManager.java:484)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfo (ApplicationPackageManager.java:466)
    at com.narb.listapp.Applications.ListApp$AppsGetInfo.fromUsageStat (ListApp.java:210)
```

EDIT

I have a friendly tester (not in the same city) who has the crash. I was able to get some data:

after infos = packageManager.getInstalledApplications:

```
ApplicationInfo{69419b2 com.sec.factory}
ApplicationInfo{e8f5d03 com.samsung.knox.knoxtrustagent}
ApplicationInfo{4b3b480 com.android.htmlviewer},
```

Before the crash:

```
com.sec.factory
com.samsung.knox.knoxtrustagent
```

so it looks like it is crashing on com.samsung.knox.knoxtrustagent?

What could be the reason? How do you workaround this?

Comment: Is that the actual stacktrace, or have you removed things like package names? The NameNotFoundException usually specifies what isn't found

Comment: This is it. I have 5 crashes like that. As I forgot to test infos returned by packageManager.getInstalledApplications(flags) could it be that it is null? I assumed that it is not the case otherwise I would have had a nullPointer error? I removed to make my code simpler the check for permission.

Comment: I have an example now where it is crashing. If you could be kind enough to look at my EDIT. Thanks!

Comment: I was wrong in my previous edit. It is com.samsung.knox.knoxtrustagent that makes it crash. I get more crashes now in prod: all samsung except 1 moto (Droid turbo 2)